# How to get input/request data for higher load test execution

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a login scenario to be tested for 10000 users, which contains phone# as input and have given in csv file. Im able to perform load testing for 10000 users and able to show the report with total samples, throughput etc post exporting to a file. However issue is customer wants proof that we are giving input as 10000 users and not using loop eg(500 threads * 2 loops). Kindly help with suggestions if we have any option to show that we are using 10000 unique users.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a listener called [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)) which shows how many users were active during this or that phase of the test

   [image]
2. [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) contains information how many threads were started for this or that [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

   [image]
3. [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) contains number of active threads, both overall and in the current Thread Group
4. [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) contains the Threads Over Time chart